# Multilined expression inside split environment

Tags: equations

There is another thread with a solution regarding this problem but that doesn't seem to work in my case and I can't diagnose why.

I have the following code

```
\begin{flalign}    
\begin{split}
        y &=\frac{\displaystyle (89.982)(788-253.7908)}{\displaystyle 6ELI} \left(\frac{\displaystyle 788}{\displaystyle (788-253.7908)}(300-253.7908)^3 + (788^2 - (788-253.7908)^2)(300)-300^3 \right)\\ \\
        &+ \frac{\displaystyle (411.6)(788-303.3825)(300)}{\displaystyle 6ELI} (788^2 - 300^2 - (788-303.3825)^2)
\end{split}&&
\end{flalign}\\
```

This is working as intended except the first equation goes too wide. After looking online I know I can use multiline for fitting in longer equations. The way I tried to use it was like this,

```
\begin{flalign}    
\begin{split}
        y &=\begin{multilined}
           \frac{\displaystyle (89.982)(788-253.7908)}{\displaystyle 6ELI} 
           \left(\frac{\displaystyle 788}{\displaystyle (788-253.7908)}(300-253.7908)^3 \\
           + (788^2 - (788-253.7908)^2)(300)-300^3 \right)
           \end(multilined) \\ \\
        &+ \frac{\displaystyle (411.6)(788-303.3825)(300)}{\displaystyle 6ELI} (788^2 - 300^2 - (788-303.3825)^2)
\end{split}&&
\end{flalign}\\
```

With the intention of breaking up the terms inside the larger bracket and extending it to a second line.

But the result I get is completely out of sorts.
[image]
The first expression is pushed to the bottom of the list. Maybe I understood the multilined environment wrong. Would appreciate any help I can get.

P.S. - I only included the first two lines from the split environment for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: You can't break `\left` and `\right` over different lines. You must use manual sizes there.

Comment: Did you really use `multilined`? It is `multlined`.

Comment: @Bernard oh no. I think my brain autocorrected the command and I've been reading it wrong. Sorry and thanks.

Comment: @campa so I need to specify the bracket size for the left and right one separately if I break them ?

Comment: why are you using split here at all flalign (I'd use align) is already a multi-liner alignment

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I wanted the equations to be aligned to the left and looking online I found that using flalign with && does the job

Comment: @Wren  no that is completely the wrong environment if you want equations left aligned use `[fleqn]` option to `\documentclass` the fl in `flalign` stands for "full length" ie uses  the full width of the page  and the align in flalign implies it is a multi-line align,ent so each row should have one or  more & and there should be multiple rows. You have a one row, one column "alignment".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some things wrong with your code:

- the environment is called `multlined`, not `multilined`;
- it should be`\end{multlined}`, not `\end(multlined)`;
- you can't break `\left` and `\right` over multiple lines.

Additional comments:

- while under certain circumstances it might make sense to have `\displaystyle` in a `\frac`, in this particular case it's not doing anything;
- I don't quite know what `ELI` is, but if you write it like this then it's `E` times `L` times `I`. If it's a multi-letter variable you might want to use`\mathit` or `\mathrm`.

Personally I would not use `multlined` in this case but rather `aligned`, but that's a matter of taste. Since I don't know what the outer`flalign` is for I just use `equation`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}% more generous margins
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}    
\begin{split}
        y ={}&
           \frac{(89.982)(788-253.7908)}{6ELI} 
           \begin{aligned}[t]
           \biggl[&\frac{788}{(788-253.7908)}(300-253.7908)^3 \\
           &+ \bigl(788^2 - (788-253.7908)^2\bigr)(300)-300^3 \biggr]
           \end{aligned} \\
        &+ \frac{(411.6)(788-303.3825)(300)}{6\mathit{ELI}} \bigl(788^2 - 300^2 - (788-303.3825)^2\bigr)
\end{split}        
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well the reason I've been using flalign instead of equation is because I want the equation to be left aligned. I found on a thread in this forum that flalign with && achieves this.

Comment: @Wren use `\documentclass[fleqn]{article}` for flush left equations.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for pointing me to fleqn David, I'm reading about it right now.

Comment: You're right about the /displaystyle, I was using it earlier where it was required and forgot I didn't need to do it here. Effectively, changing multilined to multlined was enough to fix my output but thanks a lot for the other tips. I am learning a lot.